# Resource initialization in JNDI context

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jndi

When are Resources defined in a context.xml file instantiated? Is it on application startup or is it when you call the lookup() method for the specific resource?

Sorry if it's a silly question, I've been searching for a while and can't seem to find a definite answer.